# Joomla databasefields missing where to get the sql file

Tags: php, database, joomla

I recently manually updated joomla and I'm getting the following error when trying to access the admin panel:

```
Table 'technet.lb_postinstall_messages' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `lb_postinstall_messages`
```

This is because I didn't update the database of my joomla installation. How can I do this? On the Joomla site it says I can just "click the fix button" but there is no button and when I try to access the database part in extensions it also gives an error of a missing field.

Where can I get a clean sql file of joomla 3.2.7? If I could just add the new fields in my phpmyadmin with an sql file that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all update queries in folder administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates